# Replace the type of an object property in a Flow type

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Let's say we have defined a very simple object type:

```
type A = {
  foo: string,
  bar: number,
  // ... many other properties
};
```

Now we'd like to define a variant of this type, just replacing the type of `foo` by `?string`:

```
type A2 = {
  foo: ?string,
  bar: number,
  // ... many other properties, with the same types as in A
};
```

How can that be done, without having to define the whole type again?

It'd be enough if the answer only worked in the particular case of replacing property type `T` by `?T`, since that is my most frequent problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of two solutions:

1) a parametric type alias

```
type Parametric<T> = {
  foo: T,
  bar: number,
  // ... many other properties
};

type A = Parametric<string>;
type B = Parametric<?string>;
```

2) intersections

```
type Base = {
  bar: number,
  // ... many other properties
};

type A = Base & { foo: string };
type B = Base & { foo: ?string };
```

Comment: Solution 1 would be perfect for one parameter (which is what I asked for, so I mark it as the accepted answer). However, it might become cumbersome if the number of properties to modify increases.

Comment: Is it impossible to remove a property from a type (maybe via some $Xxxx directive) without having to modify the original type?

Comment: There is `$Diff` but you end up with a different behavior: [Flowtype/try](https://flowtype.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeAoKUBmB7LAuKAzsAE4CWAdgOYA0aUARgIbH7kCuAtvRMbegPT8oAOlFQOjciChZgACx5QwxLJGLBSEAigC+AbhQpQkKACEEUACQARUhgwAeGNWSYc+ImSpQdAPgMoABRIbnhQAOSM4S5MLFAAjD74MACUBsGh+GzkACYQGBQQOTHM+Ik6+KZpQSHYYewANg0lceWVaVCCUA6IPCrENQylCUlmKZ1CPVDypARQs1CMTVgA7kUoQA)

Comment: In fact, I experimented a lot with $Diff but somehow couldn't get to a solution. I will try that way too, thanks a lot!

Comment: In the `$Diff` solution (@gcanti 's comment), not only the subtracted property is allowed to become `undefined`, but all others as well! Is that intended?

Comment: [Flowtype/try](https://flowtype.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeAoKUBmB7LAuKAzsAE4CWAdgOYA0aUARgIbH7kCuAtvRMbegPT8oAOlFQOjciChZgACx5QwxLJGLBSEAigC+AbhQAKJJhz4A5I3PUGzfAEYoO-DACUBlKEhQAQgigAJAAipBgYADwwNibYeIQkFJROAHwGxrYsUI7Ovu5GJkyZbOQAJhAYFBAlTvg+7lCCUADuctKkBOTmwFDy7VCSUDwqxAD8QA)

Comment: You are right and it was not intended. `$Diff` seems not usable for this task. Actually I try to avoid it as much as I can

Answer (score 0):

I would use the spread operator with exact types (introduced in flow v0.42.0).

```
type A = {|
  foo: string,
  bar: number,
  // ... many other properties
|}

type A2 = {
   ...A,
   foo: ?string
}
```

Note: [You need to use an exact type for A](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/1326#issuecomment-298249685) (the `{| ... |}` syntax). This is because of how flow handles unsealed (not exact) types when spreading.

Answer (score 0):

For nested properties, you can use the [$PropertyType<T, k>](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-propertytype) utility.

```js
type Type1 = {
  prop1: string,
  prop2: {
    a?: string,
    b?: number,
  }
}

type Type2 = {
  ...Type1,
  prop2: {
    ...$PropertyType<Type1, "prop2">,
    c: boolean,
  }
}

const obj: Type2 = {
  prop1: "foo",
  prop2: {
    a: "foo",
    c: true,
  }
}

const {
  prop2: {
    a,
    b,
    c
  }
}: Type2 = obj;

if (c === true) {
  // do something
}
```

[flow.org/try](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgAqueAjGALxgDeqYYOATnDqQFxgDOGjAlgHYBzADR0GzHACYOtevQCGAfg7c+Q0XLAAjZWH4BXALZa8jDWAC+qK5hJESkyjTEA6N8XylzTFtOea3FwASAAUJU2wPPAAeKK8wACIfKQSAPnN6AGMOLTg4GDx5fnMrG0y4fm4wOC0AKw4oxypZcRZ2RKg8hO8JPxaFDgTOuG6xLI4efTwS63Ryyox-VqkZMbB5DO1NzLFShocnGtqAbnReKDAACkzKCipJvABKJeBgMAATOC44QzwMAAsBIJrEA)